# Joomla website not listed in phpmyadmin

Tags: database, joomla, phpmyadmin, xampp, joomla1.7

I have finished working on a joomla! website locally using XAMPP, my OS is Vista. I need to copy the website to the client's computer so he could have a look, so i needed to export the database related to the website but all I find on my phpmyadmin are:

```
* cdcol
* information_schema
* mysql
* performance_schema
* phpmyadmin
* test
* webauth
```

the same databases are apparently present by default in phpmyadmin after installing XAMPP, could somebody have a clue regarding what could I be missing here? Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your MySQL user has no access to the database. Check your Joomla config for the data and login with them again.

Comment: I checked phpmyadmin/Previliges and the user that I use to get into phpmyadmin has All Previliges.I use the same username and password to login to the Joomla! backend and phpmyadmin.

Comment: It is not about what username/password you log into Joomla with. It is about the username/password that Joomla/PHP connects to the MySQL server with. These details are stored within Joomla's configuration.php file. It could be that you have re-used a previous database. Joomla utilises a 'table prefix' allowing its tables to be inside a db used for other purposes or even for multiple sets of Joomla database tables (from separate sites) to be stored inside one db.